# Python: writing file and using buffer

Tags: django, file, buffer

I'm using django to generate personalized file, but while doing so a file is generated, and in terms of space using it is quite a poor thing to do.

this is how i do it right now:

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    pdf.write(f) #pdf is an object of pyPDF2 library

with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    return send_file(data=f, filename=filename) #send_file is a HTTPResponse parametted to download file data
```

So in the code above a file is generated.

The easy fix would be to deleted the file after downloading it, but i remember in java using stream object to handle this case.

Is it possible to do so in Python?

EDIT:

```py
def send_file(data, filename, mimetype=None, force_download=False):
    disposition = 'attachment' if force_download else 'inline'
    filename = os.path.basename(filename)
    response = HttpResponse(data, content_type=mimetype or 'application/octet-stream')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = '%s; filename="%s"' % (disposition, filename)
    return response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the exact details of the `pdf.write` and `send_file` functions, I expect in both cases they will take an object that conforms to the [BinaryIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) interface. So, you could try using a [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) to store the content in an in-memory buffer, rather than writing out to a file:

```py
with io.BytesIO() as buf:
    pdf.write(buf)
    buf.seek(0)
    send_file(data=buf, filename=filename)
```

Depending on the exact nature of the above-mentioned functions, YMMV.

Comment: Just tried your solution, it work but no data is transmitted
FYI: pdf is an object of the library pyPDF2
and send_file is just an HTTPresponce parameted to download file

Comment: My bad! I forgot you need to seek back to the beginning of the buffer between writing and reading (also the flush is unnecessary). I've edited my answer to correct it.